# Cordova run failure on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-3

To cut this short, I have android project with cordova. Everything works fine except cordova run which gives this error. Was working on ubuntu 12.04 though. Maybe I'm missing some packages? adb devices list my device, so not sure what's wrong as only looking at cordova this weekend for the first time. Thank you for help

```
cordova run
```

Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Running app on platform "android" via command "/home/daniel/Documents/my_apps/SameSystem/platforms/android/cordova/run" --device

/home/daniel/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while running the android project.
/home/daniel/Documents/my_apps/SameSystem/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/HelloCordova-debug-unaligned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/run.js:67:22)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you already had the app installed using a different signature. I suggest modifying the signature. If that doesn't fix please update the question with the new information.